# `borrowed value does not live long enough`

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```rust
use std::time::SystemTime;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use serde_json;

fn main()
{
    let mut payload = HashMap::<&String, u64>::new();
    match SystemTime::now().duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH) {
        Ok(n) => {
            let timestamp = "timestamp".to_string();
            payload.insert(&timestamp, n.as_secs());
        }
        Err(_) => panic!("SystemTime before UNIX EPOCH!"),
    };
    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&payload).unwrap())
}
```

for which the compiler falls over with:

```
error[E0597]: `timestamp` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:11:28
   |
10 |             let timestamp = "timestamp".to_string();
   |                 --------- binding `timestamp` declared here
11 |             payload.insert(&timestamp, n.as_secs());
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
12 |         }
   |         - `timestamp` dropped here while still borrowed
...
15 |     println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&payload).unwrap())
   |                                          -------- borrow later used here
```

I can fix this by moving `let timestamp = "timestamp".to_string();` above `match`, but I can't help feeling that there is a better solution, and indeed I don't understand why the compiler doesn't make the same complaint about `n`.

Is there a solution that involves keeping the definition of `timestamp` inside the `Ok` clause?

Comment: With `timestamp` going out of scope the reference to it becomes [dangling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#dangling-references). Change to `HashMap<String, u64>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem here are those two lines:

```rust
{
    let timestamp = "timestamp".to_string();
    payload.insert(&timestamp, n.as_secs());
}
```

This is a so-called *reference to a temporal variable*. As the keys in your `HashMap` are `&String` references, the actual data of the keys are not stored in the `HashMap`. They have to live somewhere.

In your code, the place where the actual data of the key lives is in the `timestamp` variable. But after `insert()`ing, you leave the scope where the `timestamp` variable lives and it gets destroyed; the entry in the `payload` still exists though, and the key becomes a dangling reference. The compiler disallows this, hence the error.

There are two ways to fix this:

- store the keys inside of the `HashMap` by making the keys `String`
- make sure the keys outlive the `payload` object

---

### Storing the keys inside the `HashMap`

Here is how that might look like:

```rust
use serde_json;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::time::SystemTime;

fn main() {
    let mut payload = HashMap::<String, u64>::new();
    match SystemTime::now().duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH) {
        Ok(n) => {
            let timestamp = "timestamp".to_string();
            payload.insert(timestamp, n.as_secs());
        }
        Err(_) => panic!("SystemTime before UNIX EPOCH!"),
    };
    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&payload).unwrap())
}
```

```
{"timestamp":1690640840}
```

---

### Making sure the keys outlive the `HashMap`

```rust
use serde_json;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::time::SystemTime;

fn main() {
    let mut payload = HashMap::<&str, u64>::new();
    match SystemTime::now().duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH) {
        Ok(n) => {
            let timestamp = "timestamp";
            payload.insert(timestamp, n.as_secs());
        }
        Err(_) => panic!("SystemTime before UNIX EPOCH!"),
    };
    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&payload).unwrap())
}
```

```
{"timestamp":1690640900}
```

The reason this second example works is because if you don't call `to_string()` on the string, it will be a `&'static str` which is stored in global const memory and lives forever.

Note that this version now is no longer compatible with `String`s, it can only store `&str` references that definitely outlive the `payload` object. Using `String`s as keys is a little bit more wasteful, but much more flexible than using `&str`.

Comment: Really good, thorough explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`n` is not borrowed. `timestamp` is borrowed, and the borrow put in a container, then `timestamp` goes out of scope (this invalidate the container). How about a container of thinks instead of borrows.

E.g. `let mut payload = HashMap::<String, u64>::new();`.
You will have to fix one other place where `timestamp is borrowed. I will leave this for you.